# PostGIS - ST_Within or ST_Disjoint performance issues

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

I have a table of about 150,000 points in PostGIS with a spatial index and a SRID of 27700 (OS).  I want to select the points that fall outside England and Wales.  I have a multipolygon table with just one record in it (a dissolved polygon of England and Wales).

I would have thought that the following query would select this quite quickly, but it was still running after about 5 hours (I actually forgot I'd started it and was off doing something else).  I've tried a few variations using ST_Within to do it the other way around, but I can't get a result in a reasonable time (I have yet to wait for the query to finish running).  Considering the points were generating in pgRouting in about 5 mins, I'm surprised it takes this long to do any analysis of them.

Admittedly I'm using an old PC but still with 2GB of ram I would have thought this was a relatively simple query.  Is it likely that it should take this long or is something likely to be wrong. The query I've used is below:

```
SELECT pk 
FROM catchment_distance_output, england_wales_os 
WHERE ST_Disjoint (catchment_distance_output.geometry, england_wales_os.geometry);
```

I imagine I'm doing something obvious, but I'm very new to this and learning as I go.

Comment: How many vertices do you have in the polygon of england_wales_os.geometry?

Comment: ST_Disjoint is always a full table scan, since it can't make use of an index.

Comment: It could because it means the same as Not intersects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ironically, the fastest way to find the set of things **not** within other things is to do a full join that finds the contained things, but using a LEFT JOIN, so the un-matched things are hanging about to be found, thus:

```
SELECT pts.*
FROM pts LEFT JOIN polys
ON ST_Contains(polys.geom, pts.geom)
WHERE polys.id IS NULL;
```

The un-matched rows in a left join are returned as NULL so doing an IS NULL test on a column that you know is declared NOT NULL finds you all the un-matched rows.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think the main problem with performance was with my polygon geometry - obviously something wrong there as when I created a very simply container for my points (for testing only) the above query returned 11,500 records in 1516ms.  However, I also tried my original query it returned the same number of records in 41,906ms - so considerable improvement in performance.  Two important lessons learned; use your method for querying and ensure polygon geometries are valid and as simple as possible.  Thanks.