# Delete polygonal features in one layer outside polygon feature of another layer in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, query

For deleting polygonal features in one layer (~1000000 features) outside polygon feature of another layer (one feature) in PostGIS I use query:

```
DELETE FROM layer WHERE layer.id IN (SELECT a.id FROM layer a, boundary b WHERE ST_Disjoint(a.geom, b.geom));
```

Now the process takes more than 6 hours. How can I speed up the process of deleteng big count features one layer outside feature in another layer?

Comment: there is only one row in the table boundary ?

Comment: The first rule of using `DELETE` on large tables is "Don't do it".  The second rule (for experts only) is "Don't do it yet." Yet I wonder if your problem isn't the spatial query.  Please **edit** the question to specify the number of rows in the boundary table, and the time it takes to populate a temp table with a `CREATE TABLE foo AS` with your subselect query.  It would also be useful to know how many layer features are not within boundary feature(s).

Comment: @Istopopoki, yes, only one row

Comment: can you try the same query (just the select part) using [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) > 0 instead ? If it is faster you could then delete the id "NOT IN". Have also a look at this [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139880/postgis-st-within-or-st-disjoint-performance-issues).

Comment: @Istopopoki, thanks for the advice, I tried ST DWithin, it faster for 7 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially used wrong way... thanks @Vince for the advice. Now I try query like

```
CREATE TABLE layer_new AS SELECT a.* FROM layer a, boundary b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

that works fine. 232527 rows from 680000 changed on 111 seconds.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a `DELETE` at all.  I think the difference is that the second query uses `ST_Intersects`, which can take advantage of a spatial index, while the first uses `ST_Disjoint`, which cannot.